# Spring Data JPA: delete OneToMany child without going through the parent

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

My application has a `Project` entity that has set of `Resource` entities like this:

```java
@Entity
public class Project {
    @OrderBy("name ASC")
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = false)
    @Column(name = "resources")
    private Set<Resource> resources;
}
```

The `Resource` entities may be referenced by several projects, and I'm wondering how to delete a `Resource` from the database easily without first removing it from the `resources` list of each parent `Project`. Trying to delete the resource directly using the repository's `deleteById` method results in a foreign key constraint violation if the `Resouce` in question is referenced in one or more projects.

Edit: the database schema has a table called `project_resources` which maps resource IDs to project IDs.

Comment: Could you provide information on your database tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your question it seems there is a many-to-many relation between the Project and Resource tables. And based on your entity I assume on the database level there is no join table, but every Project has a Resource reference (FK) and vica versa.

Assuming this if you want to delete a resource, first you have to delete all references to it. You could execute a native update like this:

```
update Project set resource_id = null where resource_id = :resourceIdToBeDeleted;
```

After this, you can delete the resource.

---

If my assumption is wrong, and you still have a join table, then you have to delete rows from the join table. Something like this:

```
delete from Project2Resource where resource_id = resourceIdToBeDeleted;
```

After this, you can delete the resource.

In this scenario you could also model your join table with an entity, like Project2Resource and delete these entities with spring query method (`deleteByResourceId(long id)`) before the resource deletion.

Comment: Thanks Tamás, thanks for your answer. Yes I have a join table in the database.